# Android Google Vision API TextRecognizer isOperational always returns false on some devices

Tags: java, android, google-api, ocr, vision-api

I want to try one of google vision api on android. I added this line in gradle file

```
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:11.0.4'
```

also in manifest file I added this

```
 <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.vision.DEPENDENCIES"
            android:value="ocr" />
```

And here's the code snippet

```
TextRecognizer textRecognizer = new TextRecognizer.Builder(this).build();
        try {
            if (!textRecognizer.isOperational()) {
                new AlertDialog.
                        Builder(this).
                        setMessage("Text recognizer could not be set up on your device").show();
                return;
            }
}
```

So here `textRecognizer.isOperational()` always returns false. I looked to other questions and found nothing that helped me. (Device storage left 4 gb, so it's not storage issue). What I'm missing? UPDATE: I'm using LG G Flex 2 And tested same code on Samsung J7 (2017) and it works perfectly. So why G FLex2 fails?